# Is it good idea to provide UML as documentation with code?

Tags: javascript, java, class, uml, sequence

I am working on a rental-system project (website + backend + DB) which suppose to be carried forward by another team after first two releases. Just wanted to know how much helpful will the UML diagrams (like deployment diagram + sequence diagram + class diagram) be for the next batch of developers? Is yes then why we stopped using UML as documentation for all projects? If no then why?

Comment: Any sort of documentation is useful. Devs just don't want to do it. What kind of answer do you expect for your last two questions?

Comment: I recommend you answer your own question: If you were in that "next batch of developers", and received code from someone else, would *you* find that helpful? Yes, of course you would. As for "how much helpful", without a defined scale, that's impossible for us to answer for you, which is why I recommend you answer it yourself.

Comment: The best case is when you can generate your code from the UML model, in that case by definition you are sure they are synchronized and the documentation part is not out of date

Comment: I would really love if I get old/partial code with detailed UML diagrams. It would be great if code and UML will always be in sync also. But do we have any such tool yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207092/are-there-any-good-free-lightweight-linux-uml-design-tools/#answer-9207229

Answer (score 2):

ABSOLUTELY

Time and time again I argue with team leads that documentation must be created and passed along in order for a project to be sustainable. Otherwise it's up to teams to decipher code and assume what the intent was.

I've not been on a team that has even done basic application documentation/design/UML or other basic approaches for nearly 10 years. Drives me crazy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking "I am only odd person with this feeling". Do you know any good softwares (freemium) to have proper track of UMLs with code?

Comment: Also, if you find something good for UML designing post it here in your thread.