# Graphviz + Doxygen to generate UML class diagrams

Tags: uml, doxygen, graphviz

I want to use **[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)** + **[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)** to generate a class diagram based on C++ code. This works already as Doxygen comes with a native DOT support; but is it possible, to produce a **UML-like output** with the corresponding access modificators (public, private etc.), return and parameter types of the class methods, similar to the diagram below?

I'm aware of thread [How to use doxygen to create UML class diagrams from C++ source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source), but it doesn't answer the question, though.

[image]

Answer (score 66):

Create the following source file `example.cpp`:

```
class Animal
{
  public:
    void die();
    string name;
    int age;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
  public:
    void bark();
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
  public:
    void meow();
};
```

run `doxygen -g` and change the following options of the generated `Doxyfile`:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
```

run `doxygen` and look at the output for the Animal class, it should be the similar as the above picture, although doxygen will not show the return types of the methods and fields.

Comment: Is there a way to have the return types displayed?

Comment: Did you find a way to display return types, @Derek?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source/38322858#38322858 for a more complete answer

Answer (score 20):

I had similar problem its successfully solved now.

Following are the steps(assuming that you are using GUI version of Doxygen-Doxywizard)

1. Click on Expert button
2. Go to Dot tab and select the DOT_PATH.
   Browse the folder where you have installed the program.
   e.g., " C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.32/bin "

Hope it helps,
Anit

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 4):

Try [Doxygraph](https://code.google.com/p/doxygraph/)!

> Doxygraph is a collection of tools to automate reverse engineering UML class diagrams from your project's source code, and present them as interactive web apps.
>
> It relies on Doxygen to parse your source code and create an intermediate XML representation of the information it collects, so it supports all the same programming languages that Doxygen supports: C, C++, C#, Objective C, Java, Python, PHP, Tcl, D, IDL, VHDL, and Fortran.

You need to read the README from the cloned Project.

Comment: This is not an answer of the asked question. You should write this as a comment

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution to achieve your result is to use [plantuml](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/objects.html), but it requires more work on documentation.

Comment: This seems to be the right tool when you do not want to generate generic diagrams from the real code but rather have extra "diagram code" in the documentation that generates hand-crafted diagrams. This is exactly what I was looking for.