# How to show all classes in one Class diagram

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

When I do reverse-engineering in EA it imports source code in packages, but places one Class diagram per package. It is not very useful as I can't see all relations between classes(only relations in current package). Is there any option to create one diagram  from all java files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "[insert related elements](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/modeling/insertrelatedelements.htm)" function on one of the key classes and raise the number of levels to the maximum possible.

As an alternative, look at the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432016/how-to-create-class-diagram-from-source-code-using-either-enterprise-architect-o?rq=1):

> If (...) your classes are spread out among different packages and namespaces so that EA generates multiple diagrams for them, you'll have to merge them manually. Do this by opening both diagrams, selecting all (Ctrl-A) in one, copying (Ctrl-C) and pasting (Ctrl-V) into the other, then ask EA to Layout Diagram again.