# how to export class diagram from cplusplus source code using rational software architect 9.0

Tags: rational-rsa, rational-rose

I am using rational software architect 9.0. It uses like eclipse. I create a makefile project from existing code. That means I already have the c++ source code. Now I want to generate class diagram from these code. I find an article in chinese to describe how to do it using rose on website. But I dont know how to follow those steps. Because I did not find views described in those steps on my current edition, like, component view.

An eclipse is installed during installing RSA. I can open eclipse directly from the installed folder of RSA. I can import the existing source code as a project. I can see the class view from one of a header file. But just one header and one class. I dont know how to get the relation diagram of all classes from source code (hearder files or all source files including cpp files?).

I can open RSA from shortcut in desktop. I am using windows 10. But It seems not use the same workspace with eclipse. I can create an empty UML project. But what about the source code?

I still dont know how to get class diagram. [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432016/how-to-create-class-diagram-from-source-code-using-either-enterprise-architect-o) shows how to do it in EA instead of RSA 9.0

Now what I have is:

RSA9.0 which is more looks like eclipse.

source code looks like:

```
server
├───folder1
│     ├───ffirst1.h
│     ├───ffirst1.cpp
│     ├───Main.cpp
│     ├───makefile
│     ├───fsecond1.h
│     └───fsecond2.cpp
│
├───folder2
│     ├───sfirst1.h
│     ├───sfirst1.cpp
│     ├───ssecond1.h
│     ├───ssecond2.cpp
│     ├───Main.cpp
│     └───makefile
├───manager.sh
└───makefile
```

how to export class diagram from cplusplus source code(header files?) using rational software architect 9.0?

Does anyone can give me steps to this problem?

Any advices or experiences would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why down vote? please leave a comment here. Thanks.

Comment: It's a common question for users who just turn to RSA from Rose. And It's useful for users who first use RSA like me.

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432016/how-to-create-class-diagram-from-source-code-using-either-enterprise-architect-o

Comment: `That's applies to EA`

Answer (score 0):

"[Working with C++ Visualization in IBM Rational Systems Developer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0605_elamkulam/index.html)" should be one of the answers. It might be not the perfect one. But it really  can reverse class diagram from header files using `visualization` feature on the right click shortcut menu. `Visualize > Add to New Diagram File > Class Diagram`. The cplusplus project should already in the workspace, of course. At first, you should create one class diagram from a header file to a new class diagram file, then add other class diagrams from other header files in to this existed class diagram file.