# Tool to automatically create a class diagram for Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, uml, class-diagram, umbrello

I am having a problem finding a tool to create a UML class diagram for my Qt application.

I tried both **BOUML** and **Umbrello**, but both of them have problems with some classes.

I am working on Ubuntu.

Comment: You may check whether there is a version of rational rose for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) can build a lot of diagrams (inheritance, collaboration, even callflow), I think you should try it.

I used it in the past, and even if didn't commented the code as required, it was able to produce very nice (albeit complicated) diagrams.

Citing from [Features](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/features.html) section of online docs:

> - Uses the dot tool of the Graphviz tool kit to generate include dependency graphs, collaboration diagrams, call graphs, directory structure graphs, and graphical class hierarchy graphs.
> - Automatically detects public, protected and private sections, as well as the Qt specific signal and slots sections. Extraction of private class members is optional.
>
> Although doxygen can now be used in any project written in a language that is supported by doxygen, initially it was specifically designed to be used for projects that make use of Qt Software's Qt toolkit. I have tried to make doxygen `Qt-compatible'. That is: Doxygen can read the documentation contained in the Qt source code and create a class browser that looks quite similar to the one that is generated by Qt Software. Doxygen understands the C++ extensions used by Qt such as signals and slots and many of the markup commands used in the Qt sources.

Comment: FYI, a good example of using class diagrams in Doxygen is [QWT](http://qwt.sourceforge.net) documentation, e.g. in this doc for [QwtPlotHistogram](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_histogram.html). I think that all configuration used in this particular case can be found in [docs directory](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/qwt/code/trunk/qwt/doc) of its svn repo.

Comment: To get UML style diagrams, you will have to change a couple of default settings.  The answers to this [Question about Doxygen and UML diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484879/graphviz-doxygen-to-generate-uml-class-diagrams) should help.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems can import C++ code.  The diagrams are very good and the tools supports round-tripping (editing diagram and generating code).  It is interesting to see what it does with the moc_*.cpp files, but you will probably want to delete those from your model.