# How Do You Keep UML Diagrams Up To Date?

Tags: java, uml

I am from a Physics background and not a Computer Science background and never did any course at University on class/component diagrams etc and I have never found the need to use them at work.

The main thing that I don't understand is how do you keep them up to date if the code is still being developed or maintained?

e.g. What's to stop me from refactoring several methods or classes and making the class diagram obsolete?

Do you have to constantly update the diagram manually?

I have seen tools that generate UML from the code and these could keep it up to date I suppose but from what I have seen, the auto-generated diagrams don't seem to be useful enough.

Is the UML for a project likely to be created at the start then be left in a documentation folder and gradually get more and more out of date?

Answer (score 9):

I work for a moderately large government agency, so most of our major projects fall into the "Enterprise Java" category. This is what works for us:

- Architects model any changes and extensions to our corporate data model using UML diagrams. Generally there will be a conceptual model class diagram, plus a few sequence diagrams that illustrate how the various parts of the system will interact, and maybe a couple of component diagrams.
- We have a walkthrough with the business analysts, DBAs and lead developers. This idea of this is to challenge the new model, and agree on changes (there is a lot of "robust" discussion at these sessions). With a good architect, the changes are minimal.
- A senior developer creates a technical specification that will typically include a physical database ER diagram based on the architectural model. From the physical model, we automatically generate a database creation script.
- The DBAs upgrade the creation script (e.g. Add tablespace and indexspace info) and create/extend the database.
- The code gets written. Developers may create their own mini class hierarchies (e.g. POJOs to carry around data). We don't bother to model these in UML as the code should be self-documenting, and changes are inevitable as the code evolves.
- Quite often changes will occur during the development phase, especially if using agile methodologies. If these impact on the corporate data model, then the UML and ER diagrams will be updated.
- At the end of the project, the documentation is updated to reflect "as built" state.

Getting back to the  gist of your question, I'm not a great believer in automated UML <-> code generation. Generally there is data that is personal to the UML diagram (notes, relationship cardinality, sequence diagrams etc) that does not appear in the code or is very difficult to extract. Conversely the code contains stuff (e.g. behavioural method working logic, data structures and caches) that do not necessarily show in the logical UML model. Then there is the whole question of how you map the logical model class hierarchy to database tables...

To summarise, I recommend:

- Get the design correct up front. Changes to the logical model are expensive and awkward to implement.
- Use a modelling tool that will support all of the artifacts you need from the same data source. That is, the initial UML logical model, the database ER diagram and the database creation SQL DDL. We use Enterprise Architect, but there are lots of other tools that will do this.
- Use UML to model the "big picture" and forget it for describing detailed coding. A good rule of thumb is you need UML if any change to the model affects more than just your team. (e.g. A new database field may require a change to the database, a change to a web service, a change to the GUI and a change to a mainframe batch process. UML has a place in defining the data change in a way multiple teams can understand)

Comment: Should be in boldface: **Get the design correct up front.** and **Use UML to model the "big picture" and forget it for describing detailed coding.**

Comment: @laune Thanks for the kind words

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a question that is normally answered on SO, here's what I've seen and heard:

A project's SW development plan must define how design is being done, and if UML is used, how an update to the SW must be made. That plan can define that the UML is "one shot" - so it is indeed forgotten after the first design progresses into code. OTOH, a strict follow-up rule and ensuing checking may require and guarantee that the UML design is updated during bug fixes (if required) or more extensive changes. (More often than not, you  may even have to go back to requirements and update there, too.)

A completely different approach is to generate code from UML - that way you never change the code. Whether this works or not, given the potential differences between UML's expressiveness and what and how a language like Java or C++ provide to implement the semantics of the various diagrams, is a question I'd dearly love to have answered on more reliable data than a salesman's pitch.

Answer (score 0):

As for my experience, class UML diagrams are mostly useless. Generic code changes too often, thus having UML diagrams for it adds too much burden.

Possible exceptions are:

- Architecture (component-level) diagrams. Created once, changes rarely, useful for others
- Business model. If your application operates on complex model, it may be worth it to generate classes from UML representation. This UML can become quite valuable if you have *many* applications operating on the same model.
- University projects - no comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you choose, what you agree on with the team and stakeholders, what are your priorities, what are your processes and their deliverable artifacts and what are the costs and who will pay them.

As of today there are no production-ready tools or machines to keep the UML documentation up-to-date completely automatically although many are close, e.g. [Graphviz + Doxygen to generate UML class diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484879/graphviz-doxygen-to-generate-uml-class-diagrams)
and many make this task easier, e.g. [Sparx Systems's Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/mdg/int/vs/index.html) or [Rapid Quality Systems's Code Rocket](http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Support/CodeRocketForVisualStudio/Screenshots)

As any other process the UML documentation creation/maintenance is a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_modeling) that needs to be defined, implemented, managed, optimized (same way as you need to manage experiments in Physics which you already know)

There is a whole website devoted to this topic at [Agile Modeling - Effective Practices for Modeling and Documentation](http://www.agilemodeling.com)

[image]