# Decoding data structures

Tags: c, data-structures, visualization

I am wondering if there is a graphical tool to decode data structures from multiple files? What I mean is, let us say we have the following

```
typedef struct herStruct;
 ...
typedef struct myStruct
{
   void* hisStruct;
   herStruct* ptr;
}myStruct;
```

It would have been great if there was a tool where in, we pass the header files and c files and the tool would give a graphical representation of the various structures used. Wishful thinking I know.
I am going through linux drivers (custom drivers) and it feels convoluted understanding the various structures.  How does one understand someone else's code which has so many structures and is convoluted (and not many comments!). I tried to draw it myself, but did not go too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Doxygen/GraphViz to generate visualizations.
Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484879/graphviz-doxygen-to-generate-uml-class-diagrams).

Comment: Thanks!.I will take a look at it. The linux driver i am working with doesnt have doxygen. But looks like i can feed the source files to doxygen tool to generate the required uml files and then use graphviz.