# Graphviz + Doxygen not generatint UML class diagrams

Tags: doxygen, graphviz

I am trying to generate a UML graph with Doxygen, but UML_LOOK is not working as expected, and I cannot find anything that could be wrong. Even though I tried everything on [Graphviz + Doxygen to generate UML class diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484879/graphviz-doxygen-to-generate-uml-class-diagrams), the result is:

[End not-UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Ooa.png)

My config is the following:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = D:/DCasado/Desktop
TAB_SIZE               = 2
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = ctl=c++
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = YES
INPUT                  = NTGYProj_sys1/scripts
RECURSIVE              = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
CHM_FILE               = buscando.chm
HHC_LOCATION           = "C:/Program Files (x86)/HTML Help Workshop/hhc.exe"
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 50
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
DOT_PATH               = "../../../Program Files/Graphviz/bin"
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 100
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
```

I tried deleting the output files and arbitrary changing the configs, but it keeps generating the same graphs that generates when UML_LOOK is disabled.

Update: It is generating as expected the UML diagram inside each class in the `Collaboration Diagram` and the `Inheritance diagram`, but not in the Class Hierarchy, which is the one that matters to me.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Did doxygen find the dot executable? The `DOT_PATH               = "../../../Program Files/Graphviz/bin"` might be different from what you expect, maybe you should use here `DOT_PATH               = "C:/Program Files/Graphviz/bin"` analogoust to what you did for the `HHC_LOCATION`.

Comment: @albert doxygen version is 1.9.8. Graphviz is properly found, because it is generating a graph diagram, as shown on the "End not-UML diagram" image. Before I added the correct path (because on the beginning I failed on that), doxygen was throwing an error when trying to find graphviz, which is not happening anymore. Still, I'll follow your advice and I'll change the path style.

Comment: You mention "but not in the Class Hierarchy", doxygen does not follow the UML-look here (would blow up the page quite a bit) , but the individual parts can be found by clicking on the elements.Or did I miss something? Regarding the DOT_PATH` when `dot` can be found in the `PATH` / `path` one can leave here the `DOT_PATH` empty.

Comment: @albert I see. It would've been great though, as I need a UML diagram of my project, and doing it manually will kill me. Thank you anyways.
Btw, I'm not too familiar with stack overflow conventions. What should I do now with this question?

Comment: Maybe create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues) specifying the required enhancement (I'm not too optimistic about it though).