# How can I see a produced by Doxygen class-diagramm?

Tags: c++, uml, doxygen, graphviz, doxywizard

I have read this two themes:
[How to use doxygen to create UML class diagrams from C++ source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source?lq=1)
and [Graphviz + Doxygen to generate UML class diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484879/graphviz-doxygen-to-generate-uml-class-diagrams/9488742#9488742)

And I did all like guys wrote there, but I still have a problem - **I can't find produced file with class-diagramm (or a corresponding page at resulting html)**. The only "diagramm" I found is "Class Hierarchy" (see linked print-screen below).

Please, help me to find, where this file (or a corresponding page of resulting html) is. Or may be I didn't do something else to get the resulting class-diagramm?

Thanks a lot!

[image: NOT_a_class-diagramm]