# Can't create graphviz graph inside Doxygen html

Tags: doxygen-wizard

I've installed Graphviz, Doxygen on Windows 7. Now, I do have cygwin64 installed, but I don't care, I just want the doxyfiles to have graphs.
I use the CMD prompt or cygwin, it fails on both. everything is installed under Windows7

No matter what I do I cannot get Doxygen to generate docs with graphs embedded in them.

I did this...
[How to use doxygen to create UML class diagrams from C++ source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source)

No luck, It just does not work, so I set DOT_CLEANUP = NO. Still no luck.

I'm running inside c:\labs. I do a C:\Doxygen Doxfile

I get...

```
finalizing index lists...
Running dot...
Generating dot graphs using 5 parallel threads...
Running dot for graph 1/3
Running dot for graph 2/3
Running dot for graph 3/3
Error: dot: can't open /cygdrive/c/labs/html/classA__coll__graph.dot
error: Problems running dot: exit code=2, command='dot', arguments='"/cygdrive/c/labs/html/classA__coll__graph.dot" -Tpng -o "/cygdrive/c/labs/html/classA__coll__graph.png"'
Error: dot: can't open /cygdrive/c/labs/latex/classA__coll__graph.dot
error: Problems running dot: exit code=2, command='dot', arguments='"/cygdrive/c/labs/latex/classA__coll__graph.dot" -Tpdf -o "/cygdrive/c/labs/latex/classA__coll__graph.pdf"'
Error: dot: can't open /cygdrive/c/labs/html/graph_legend.dot
error: Problems running dot: exit code=2, command='dot', arguments='"/cygdrive/c/labs/html/graph_legend.dot" -Tpng -o "/cygdrive/c/labs/html/graph_legend.png"'
Patching output file 1/2
error: problems opening map file /cygdrive/c/labs/html/classA__coll__graph.map for inclusion in the docs!
```

If I run under cygwin, I get the same thing. I've tried using the Doxywizard also.

Why can't I generate the diagrams?

Thanks for help,

Comment: Looks like a combination of using a Cygwin doxygen executable and a Windows dot version resulting in a mixture of path definitions.

Comment: @Mike, did you ever solve this_ If so, please tell us how.

Comment: @Mawg - I didn't ask the question, I only edited it. Albert gave some indications of something to investigate, though.

Comment: Albert? Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As @Albert suggested, this is caused by trying to mix Cygwin doxygen with Windows dot (graphviz).  I ran into the same problem which led me here.  I ran `which doxygen` and `which dot` to determine that my doxygen was coming from Cygwin but my dot was coming from a Windows installation of graphviz.

The solution for me was to run the Cygwin setup and add/install graphviz.  After doing so, the errors went away.