# How to get automatic relationships in class diagram VS2017?

Tags: c#, .net, class, visual-studio-2017, diagram

I need to create a UML class diagram for my .net core project. If I go to Class View - View Class Diagram, I get all of my classes, but there are no relationships and to do them by hand is a lot of work. How can it be done automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no automatic relationships in  VS 2017 , you must right-click on the  field and select Show As Collection Association. Check below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in Visual Studio, but I know you can achieve this by using [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) and [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/).

These SO posts might be of great help:

[How to use doxygen to create UML class diagrams from C++ source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source)

[Graphviz + Doxygen to generate UML class diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484879/graphviz-doxygen-to-generate-uml-class-diagrams/9488742)

I also found this tool online: https://code.google.com/archive/p/doxygraph/

Never tested it but based on its description it seems to do exactly what you want.