# Doxygen to create VBA Documentation

Tags: vba, uml, documentation, doxygen, class-diagram

Hello I am trying to create a documentation for my VBA Code with doxygen. I was able to create a Documentation of the general structure however I have a problem:

The program does not create any class-diagrams for the modules - only for my classes. Is it possible to create class diagrams for my modules as well as seen i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source)

How can I setup doxygen to treat the modules just like the classes? I am aware that the modules in VBA are not classes but I think the visualization as such would be helpful for the documentation.

I am using doxygen with these [configurations](https://github.com/sevoku/doxygen-vb-filter/blob/master/samples/Doxyfile.windows) 
and the vbfilter from [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html)