# Qt C++ class diagrams?

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

I see very extensive Qt C++ class documentation, e.g. at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html. But does the documentation include class inheritance diagrams so that we may quickly see how these are all related?

Comment: Usually it's not necessary. There are no deep inheritance. And documentation organized very good - so you will see all members (including inherited) in one list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DmitrySazonov mentioned, usually it's not necessary to see whole Qt C++ class diagram.

But if you have this special needs, here is quite good and working scenario.
Since Qt has well documented source code and this code is [qDoc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/01-qdoc-manual.html)-powered (which is compatible with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)). You may generate required diagrams by yourself. *(I'm not sure how much time will it take you, but probably get some popcorn beforehand)*

I'll show you example how to prepare diagrams for `QtConcurrent` module only (doxygen work took me ~8s on i7-6820HQ).

1. Install doxygen. Typically:

```
sudo apt install doxygen
```

2. Get and unpack Qt sources (http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.3/single/).
3. Use console and navigate to `qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/`.
4. Generate standard `Doxygen` file by command:

```
doxygen -g
```

5. Edit `qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/Doxygen`. Append next lines (or make sure that everywhere in `Doxyfile` any assignments of these variables are commented):

```
EXTRACT_ALL          = YES
CLASS_DIAGRAMS       = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS = NO
HAVE_DOT             = YES
CLASS_GRAPH          = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH  = YES
UML_LOOK             = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS = 50
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS   = YES
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES  = 100
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH  = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT      = YES
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38322858/867349).

Find `INPUT` section and put:

```
INPUT                  = concurrent
```

Find `GENERATE_LATEX` section and change to :

```
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
```

**NOTE:** If you are familiar with `doxygen`, edit `Doxyfile` as you wish -- there are plenty of possible settings like logo, additional texts, file patterns, excludes etc.

6. To generate doxygen documentation just run `doxygen`.

As a result you'll get folder `qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/src/html` with generated documentation. Open `index.html`.

---

To see results [refer to this page](https://troyane.github.io/QtSrc2UML/).