# Doxygen UML not showing type of attributes, methods and their arguments and returns

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to add to my UML diagram information about type of attributes, methods and their arguments and returns, but I can't find appropriate flag to set. What should I set to achieve this?

I have:

[image: This is what I have]

I want to achieve:

[image]

My Doxyfile:

```
    # Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = /home/adrian/Dokumenty/eclipse/0_FULL_GAME/headers
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
INPUT                  = /home/adrian/Dokumenty/eclipse/0_FULL_GAME/headers
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ALLEXTERNALS           = YES
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 14
UML_LOOK               = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 0
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
```

Comment: In the past this request has been made as well (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7686). The biggest problem will be that they will become quite fast unreadable.

Comment: I was afraid about readability. Is there a solution for member types or method returns?

Comment: No actions have been taken.

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen has little support for UML diagramas and doesn't allow much customization.
I think you should use another tool if you want to generate UML diagrams from C++ code, like [Visual Paradigm](https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/code-engineering/cpp-round-trip/how-to-generate-uml-from-cpp-in-round-trip/) or [Enterprise Architect](https://sparxsystems.com/products/ea/) (I'm not sure if they are free).

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source) useful.

Comment: So it might not be possible?

Comment: I'm almost sure it's not. In the [official documentation](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html) there are only two UML options. The native ones are only to toggle it and limit the number of fields. The ones [related to PlantUml](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdstartuml) won't help you because this tool use a [manual specification](https://plantuml.com/class-diagram), and I don't think that's what you want...